# Mysql Geometry Closest Locations Distance

Tags: mysql, geometry, coordinates, distance

I am trying to find the closest addresses to each other in my database. I can easily find the closest addresses to a specific coordinate ie -1.1337599754333496, 53.52299880981445 ...

```
SELECT st_distance_sphere(
    address.coordinates,
    POINT(-1.1337599754333496, 53.52299880981445 )
) AS distance
FROM address
ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Is there a way to order the entire database by distance or extract a subset of the X nearest neighbours ? After wracking my brains all day I am starting to think that there isn't :-(

Comment: Yes, but you will have to calculate the distance from your 'specific coordinate' to the current row and then sort by that result  - select  st_distance(
  st_geomfromtext('point(33.099993 -97.34099)',4326),                     
  st_geomfromtext('point(33.009335 -97.22672)',4326)
  )  as distance;

Comment: Wouldn't that mean equidistant locations from origin would be next to each other, ie Leeds and Sheffield are about 20 miles from Doncaster but they are not next to each other.